# Returning Wrong value in LINQ .Any()

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a method which return a List of Class object.
After getting the list I want to check whether a specific entry exists or not
Below is my query

```
var myList = GetMethod()
if(myList != null && myList.Select(x => x.Id=='MyId').Any())
{
 // Do work
}
```

If the `mylist` is not null then `myList.Select(x => x.Id=='MyId').Any()` is always returning true even if a matching entry is not there.

Can someone help me in this?

Comment: Did you mean `myList.Any(x => x.Id=='MyId')`?

Comment: `if (myList?.Any(x => x.Id == "MyId") == true) {...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you need a `Where` over a `Select`:

```
if(myList != null && myList.Where(x => x.Id=='MyId').Any())
```

Now the `Select` ends up with an enumerable of booleans... Some are true, some are false.

You could simply that to:

```
if(myList != null && myList.Any(x => x.Id=='MyId'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Select returns an `IEnumerable` of booleans whether the condition was true for each item or not. So, `Any()` is always returning true as long as there are items in your list.

Just use:

```
    myList?.Any(x => x.Id == "MyId") == true;
```

Note that I don't like boolean comparisons like `== true` but this is for the null-check with `?.` upfront.

Comment: If you hate `==true` why not `myList?.Any(x => x.Id == "MyId") ?? false` instead. It conveys more meaning IMO.

Comment: That's what I use in my code base as well, anyway thanks for pointing out.